# Firebase phone auth issue

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am using react native with firebase, phone auth of the firebase create account if not already exists(default behaviour), So how can create check point that if user doesn't exists then it should register first then login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than check if a user was registered previously, the best approach is to just [sign in the user normally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) and then handle the case where the user's data document doesn't exist.

This prevents having to develop a way to check if a phone number has been registered previously and helps avoid leaking the stored phone numbers if you implemented it poorly.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(
  () => firebase.auth().currentUser || undefined
);
const initializingUser = user === undefined;

useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);

const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
const initializingUserData = userData === undefined;

useEffect(() => {
  if (initializingUser)
    return; // do nothing yet
  
  if (!user) {
    setUserData(null);
    return;
  }

  // clear out any stale data
  setUserData(undefined);

  return firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .onSnapshot({
      next(snapshot) {
        setUserData(!snapshot.exists ? null : snapshot.data());
      },
      error(err) {
        // TODO: handle errors
      }
    });
}, [user && user.uid]); // only rerun when the user ID changes (between undefined, null and different IDs)

useEffect(() => {
  if (initializingUser || initializingUserData)
    return; // do nothing yet

  if (!user) {
    // not logged in, go to login if not already here
    navigator.navigate("Login");
    return;
  }

  if (userData) {
    // has user data, take to dashboard
    navigator.navigate("Dashboard");
    return;
  }

  // no user data, take to profile setup
  navigator.navigate("CompleteProfile");
}, [user, userData]);
```