# How to remove data on logout when using firebase and react query?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, react-query

When my user logs out, I want to remove all user data from the app, but I'm having trouble implementing this.

I have a custom useUserData() hook that gets the user's data. getUser() is a callable cloud function. This is my code so far.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query"
import { getUser } from "Services/firebase/functions"
import firebase from "firebase/app"

export default function useUserData(){
    const [ enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()

    useEffect(_ => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setEnabled(Boolean(user))
            if (!user){
                // remove data
            }
            else queryClient.invalidateQueries("user", { refetchActive: true, refetchInactive: true })
        })

        return unsubscribe()
    }, [])

    return useQuery(
        "user", 
        () => getUser().then(res => res.data),
        {
            enabled
        }
    )
}
```

Edit:

It seemed that I was handling my effect cleanup wrong. This seems to be working.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query"
import { getUser } from "Services/firebase/functions"
import firebase from "firebase/app"

export default function useUserData(){
    const [ enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    useEffect(_ => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setEnabled(Boolean(user))    
            if (!user) {
                queryClient.removeQueries("user")
            } 
        })
        
        return _ => unsubscribe()
    }, [])

    return useQuery(
        "user", 
        () => getUser().then(res => res.data),
        {
            enabled
        }
    )
}
```

Weirdly enough, the query still fetches once after logging out, when the query should already be disabled.

Comment: Do you mean deleting it on the server? Or just clearing it ready for another user to log in?

Comment: @samthecodingman clearing it. I want to remove user data from the cache and from the ui.

Comment: Tried this approach? [keeping user data up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67625369/3068190)

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and mark it as such for user visibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my current implementation which seems to work fine.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import firebase from "firebase/app"

export default function useAuthenticatedQuery(key, func, options){
    const [ enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    useEffect(_ => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setEnabled(Boolean(user))    
            if (!user){
                queryClient.setQueryData(key, _ => undefined)
                queryClient.removeQueries(key, _ => undefined)
            }else 
                queryClient.invalidateQueries(key, { refetchActive: true, refetchInactive: true })
        })
        return _ => unsubscribe()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    return useQuery(
        key,
        func,
        {
            ...options,
            enabled
        }
    )
}
```

I use it just like the regular useQuery hook:

```
import useAuthenticatedQuery from "Hooks/useAuthenticatedQuery"

export default function useUserData(){

    return useAuthenticatedQuery(
        "user", 
        () => getUser().then(res => res.data)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
queryClient.removeQueries("user")
```

will remove all user related queries. It's a good thing to do on logout. You can clear everything by calling `removeQueries` without parameters.

Comment: this doesn't seem to affect the ui though.

Comment: hmmm how should it affect the ui? I was thinking that after logout, there won't be a query rendered on the screen? If you remove a query, and then render a `useQuery` again, it will start fetching from scratch. You can also try `resetQueries`, but it will inform subscribers about the change if you have any: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientresetqueries

Comment: I have some posts that have a like button. When a user is logged in it should show either an outlined button or a filled button depending if the user liked it. Once the user logs out, only the outlined button should be shown. I'm not performing any redirects during logout so the posts and the like buttons are still being rendered. Should I add the logic for detecting logout in the render logic of the like buttons instead?

Answer (score 5):

### Remove all queries on logout

use the below line in your onLogout function. This will remove the cache for all queries.

```
queryClient.removeQueries();
```

> It's ideal to clean all the cache after logout, else next login will show the data of the previous login for a split second.

To observe the above-mentioned behavior use `<ReactQueryDevtools />` [DOCS](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/devtools)

You can remove specific cache by passing the queryKey like so. [DOCS](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientremovequeries)

```
queryClient.resetQueries({ queryKey, exact: true })
```