# React Query: removeQueries in React Native throws

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, react-query

I'm trying to use RQ in react native (RN) and tried to follow the recommended `removeQueries()` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635388/618099

```js
export default () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>()
  const { setCurrentPortfolioId } = useCurrentPortfolio()
  const { removeQueries } = useQueryClient()

  const clearMemory = async () => {
    setCurrentPortfolioId(null)
    try {
      removeQueries()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    await setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)

    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('EMAIL')
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('PASSWORD')

    navigation.replace('SignIn')
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={clearMemory} label="LOG UD" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

but it just throws

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.queryCache')
at node_modules/react-query/lib/core/queryClient.js:122:21 in removeQueries
```

does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

---

(yes, the app screens are wrapped in a queryClientProvider)

```js
function onAppStateChange(status: AppStateStatus) {
  // React Query already supports in web browser refetch on window focus by default
  if (Platform.OS !== 'web') focusManager.setFocused(status === 'active')
}

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: { queries: { retry: 2, cacheTime: 1000 } },
})

export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources()
  useOnlineManager()

  useAppState(onAppStateChange)

  if (!isLoadingComplete) return null

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <CredentialsContextProvider>
          <CurrentPortfolioContextProvider>
            <Navigation />
          </CurrentPortfolioContextProvider>
        </CredentialsContextProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Need to pass a query key.

Comment: Does not make any difference @AG tried passing it and it still blows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws because it's a class. So has to be called like `queryClient.removeQueries()`

figured it out - somehow I deleted the sign out request without noticing it - so it was requesting it with the wrong credentials ‍♂️

leaving this answer in case it helps others